# doesn't toggle the feedback div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#feedback').hide('');

$('a#1').click(function(){
$('#feedback').toggle('');
});


});
</script>
```

It doesn't toggle the feedback div, but if you use show instead of toggle the script works.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting it differently (below is demonstration):

```
<a id="test" href="#" onclick="test(this.rel)" rel="1">Click me</a><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change"/>

function test(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
function change() {
    document.getElementById('test').rel = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CD7Uj/

Using the `rel` attribute, you can update the value that is used by your `onclick` function handler, so that you could have:

```
addplaylist('$watch',this.rel);
```

And use another function to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; it's generated on the server side. What you *can* do is replace the click handler once the page has been loaded, although it'd be easier if the anchor tag had an id... if it's worth it.

Easier yet, create a function that just delegates to the original function:

```
function addplaylist(watch, val) {
    originalAddplaylist(watch, '2');
}
```

(Better yet, change it on the server side.)